# Is this aggregate initialization or default initialization in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, aggregate-initialization

Consider following program.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a=int{};
    std::cout<<a;
}
```

Is it uses aggregate initialization or default initialization? I am confused.

Comment: @Downvoters: Who downvoted? Why downvotes?  What's wrong in question?

Comment: An `int` is not an aggregate.

Comment: It is default initialization. Aggregate initialization would be `int a[] = {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: @CoryKramer: So, why it won't work in C?

Comment: @CoryKramer This is not default initialization. It (`int{}`) is list-initialization, which in this case performs *value-initialization*.

Comment: Because `C` doesn't have `<iostream>` or `std::cout`?

Comment: @meet Only C++ has brace/uniform initialization syntax

Comment: @CoryKramer: replace <iostream> and std::cout with <stdio> & printf().

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the following phrases mean in C++: zero-, default- and value-initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empty parentheses or braces (`T()` or `T{}`) perform [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). The exception would be the case where the type is an aggregate in which case aggregate initialization would be used. Since `int` is not an aggregate, it will be value initialized and since it's not a class nor an array, value initialization will do zero-initialization.

You were wondering why it doesn't work in C. Such syntax simply doesn't exist in C, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17589839/2079303).

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer with explanation & link.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate initialization is a type of *list* initialization, which initializes *aggregates*. An aggregate is an object of type array, or object which has the characteristics defined on [this page.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

In this case, the type of initialization is most likely [value initialization.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11, by comparison with other SO answers (e.g.: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46635337/10750537) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051468/10750537)), I would say this is:

1. a [*value-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (`int{}`) followed by
2. a [*copy-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (`int a=int{}`).

By the way, from [C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), the second step should vanish as `int{}` is required to directly initialize `a`.