# C/C++: How does int array[10]={0} work?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, initialization

I am wondering how does `int array[10]={0}` really work?

Does it go all the way through the entire array like this?

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) array[i]=0;
```

Or is it more efficient?

Comment: it's probably more efficient, like `memset`

Comment: It is compiler dependent.

Comment: `Or is it more efficient?` That may depend on the compiler or even the CPU.

Comment: Fully depends on a compiler. On the one I am using it is calling some internal `memclr` function, which is built around `memset`.

Comment: Check the assembly.

Comment: Some compilers could just place initialized data into object code. So there will be no initializing code at all.

Comment: @KonstantinL It is impossible if it has an automatic storage class.

Comment: Try https://godbolt.org/ to see the asm code for different compilers / CPUs.

Comment: @EugeneSh., "could", not "will in every case".

Comment: While everyone is right that this is compiler-dependent, I think the more important point is that as long as you're using a sane compiler it's probably going to be as efficient as possible (or very close to it). You would be insane to try to optimize this yourself if your compiler supports this syntax.

Comment: Reopend the question is the OP is not asking if `int array[10]={0}` makes all the elements 0 but how that process is actually implemented and how efficient it is.

Comment: This question had 5(!) heavily downvoted answers (4 of which are deleted now). Kinda abnormal, given the question is pretty simple to answer and the full answer can be easily derived from the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the scope of your variable.

1. Global scope - `array` will be placed in the .bss segment and zeroed before call to the `main` function. Is it faster? It is definitely different as zeroing takes place before the `main` start
2. Local scope - the `{0}` initialisation will be IMO faster as those internal routines are well optimised for the particular hardware. I have tested with gcc & VS and it is quicker - but of course there is no guarantee that your compiler will do it the same way. https://godbolt.org/g/JdTPHJ

Answer (score 3):

Using {0} is one of the most misleading things in C++.

```
int array[10]={n1, n2, n3};
```

This will fill the first three elements with the values in {}. The rest of the array will be initialized with the default value - 0 for int.

```
int array[10]={1}; // [1, 0, 0, 0...]
```

It's better to use

```
int array[10]={}; // [0, 0, 0, 0...]
```

Comment: How is this even answering the question? And empty initializer is not allowed in C https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589533/is-an-empty-initializer-list-valid-c-code. How the heck it is receiving upvotes?

Comment: @Eugene a good answer doesn't have to answer the question as long as it adds clarity. There is a wrong assumption in the question which I cleared up.