# C - Meaning of empty terminator in struct array initialization

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, device-tree

While going through PCIe driver, I see this type of struct array initialization

```
static struct pci_device_id DWC_ETH_QOS_id[] = {
    { PCI_DEVICE(VENDOR_ID, DEVICE_ID), },
    { },
}
```

I found similar code in device tree **of_device_id** initializer as well:

```
static const struct of_device_id rh850_match_table[] = {
    { .compatible = "renesas,rh850" },
    { }
};
```

Why is there an empty {} at the end?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Presumably other code takes a pointer to the array without knowing its size, and needs an empty sentinel element at the end in order to know when it must stop reading. Chances are that reading code that uses these would show that.

Comment: I see your point:  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.76/source/drivers/of/base.c#L997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISO C grammar requires an initialiser list to be non-empty, however, some compilers (e.g. GCC) permit this.

Here is a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.c/kic8hJDWQGU/vEH4bPqre44J) on the topic.

The answer to what happens if its empty (do you get as-if-zero if there is no = {...} part) is "yes if the object has static duration, no if not".

Personally I initialize with values I know and do not depend on undefined behaviour.  It could limit code portability but I suspect that is not an issue in the community where this practice is common (Linux drivers where GCC is the default compiler.

Comment: Don't the uninitialized elements all get default initialized, which in C means zeroed?

Comment: If an initializer doesn't provide values for all elements/members, the remaining elements/members are default initialized, regardless of whether the object is static or not. The standard doesn't provide for `{ }`, but presumably the same rule would apply.

Comment: @KeithThompson In case at least one member variable is initialized explicitly then  `{}` might hold true for an array member variable? http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21

Comment: @Observer: Not sure what you're asking. C doesn't specify the semantics of `{}`, but we can make reasonable inferences.

Comment: I don't see any discussion of the empty initialiser in the discussion you linked. Here is a real one: [Is an empty initializer list valid C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589533/is-an-empty-initializer-list-valid-c-code) The answer is indeed no.

Comment: OP asked about other aspects of such initializer.

Answer (score 3):

As @underscore_d pointed out, **{}** is added as a sentinel element so that the code that loops over these arrays knows when to stop. It relies on the last 'empty' sentinel element as the termination condition.

The code that relies on the sentinel element:

struct of_device_id table:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.76/source/drivers/of/base.c#L997

struct pci_device_id:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.35/source/drivers/pci/pci-driver.c#L246