# Problems translating message to B1FF language

Tags: c

> I wrote a program that translates a sentence into B1FF language. When i enter a message and hit enter, it doesn't give any output, using a specific piece of code. I can make it work when i write the code in a specific way but i choose to write it in another way, which should be similar. Can you explain why it doesn't work?
>
> This piece of code works for my program and i thought it was similar to the other code:
>
> for(;(message[len] = getchar()) != '\n';)
>           len++;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 50

int main() {
char message[N];
int len=0;
printf("Enter message: ");
/*this is the part that is not working and i have no idea why. I 
  thought it's similar to the other code i provided*/
do {
    message[len] = getchar();
    len++;
} while (message[len] != '\n');

for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    switch(toupper(message[i])) {
        case 'A': putchar('4'); break;
        case 'B': putchar('8'); break;
        case 'E': putchar('3'); break;
        case 'I': putchar('1'); break;
        case 'O': putchar('0'); break;
        case 'S': putchar('5'); break;

        default: putchar(toupper(message[i])); break;
    }
}
printf("!!!!!!!!!!");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You are incrementing `len`, so `message[len]` is becoming uninitialized. Then you test it against `\n`.

Comment: What is wrong with testing against \n?

Comment: Hint: use `fgets`, instead of rolling out your own.

Comment: Testing uninitialized member against whatever is wrong.

Comment: @rassser _What is wrong with testing against \n?_ Nothing is wrong with that, but you need to test the right thing against `'\n'`. E.g. `message[len]` -> `message[len-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few observations about the sample code. Here

```
len++;
message[len] != '\n' /* at this stage message[len] contains Garbage not the valid char due to len++ */
```

`len` gets incremented before `message[len] != '\n'` statement and then accessing `len+1` characters of array causes undefined behavior. To avoid this you can check like

```
message[len-1] != '\n'
```

Next, `message` array is not null terminated. After coming out from loop end the array with `'\0'`. For e.g

```
message[len] = '\0';
```

Best way is to initialize char array while declaring itself. For e.g

```
char message[50] = {}; /* zeroed the whole array */
```

Comment: Null termination in the given code is not necessary as the array is not treated as string anyway.

Comment: Empty  initializer is not standard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589533/is-an-empty-initializer-list-valid-c-code