# does the value of a variable change itself when it is given in a for loop

Tags: c, variables, output, runtime-error

when i scanned 't' value is 1 but by the end of the loop its value is changed to 2 without any incrementation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i,t,n,a[]={},b[]={},k=0,p;
printf("enter the number ");
scanf("%d",&t);
for(p=0;p<t;p++)
{


    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n-2;i++)
    {
       // printf("\nhello");
        if((a[i+1]-a[i])!=1)
        b[k]=a[i];
        k++;
    }
    printf("\n%d",t);
}
return 0;
}
```

output:
enter the number 1
4
1
2
4

2

Comment: please read the tags description when you ask a question

Comment: `int a[] = {}` - what do you think this does ? How many items does this array have ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker That's simply a syntax error. It will not compile cleanly on a comforming C compiler.

Comment: @Lundin - sure, but that wasn't the intent of my comment. I was trying to point out to the OP the huge red flag of a dimensionless array, which should have been noticed *before* the compiler even got involved.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker It's a common problem that sloppy teachers tell students to compile with gcc as-is. And it defaults to non-standard goo.

Comment: @Lundin : all the more reason to train your good old eyeball to detect these issues, rather than rely solely on the compiler. Hence my comment.

Answer (score 1):

`int a[]={};` is not valid C, [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589533/is-an-empty-initializer-list-valid-c-code). The reason it compiles is because you are using the gcc compiler in non-standard mode.

Unfortunately gcc comes like that out of the box. To use gcc to compile code according to the C language specification, you need to use `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` instead. Where C11 is the current mainstream version of the standard and `-pedantic-errors` gives compiler errors when your code doesn't follow that standard.

Advanced: the reason why gcc allows `{}` in non-standard mode is related to [zero-length arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length) and pre-standard flexible array members - old non-standard things that pre-date the older C standard called C99, released over 20 years ago. These old features are not something anyone, least of all a beginner, should use or care about.

The GNU C language extensions don't mention what will happen when you access such an array out of bounds. Apparently it crashes just like a standard array.

What you should do instead if the array size isn't known at compile-time:

- Always compile with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`.
- Take the array size as input.
- After you know the size, allocate space for it. Preferably with dynamic memory allocation:

  ```
  int* array = malloc(n * sizeof(*array)); // where n is the number of items
  ...
  free(array);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The arrays `a` and `b` are not given an explicit size and their initializer lists are empty.  This means the arrays have a size of 0, and attempting to read or write to those arrays will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Move the definitions of the array after a value has been read for `n`, then use `n` as the array size.

```
int i,t,n,k=0,p;
printf("enter the number ");
scanf("%d",&t);
for(p=0;p<t;p++)
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n], b[n];
    ...
```