# What is the need of empty braces '{ }' at the end of array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, linux-kernel

I hit some [c](/questions/tagged/c) [code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_conntrack_l3proto_ipv4.c#L246) in Linux kernel:

```
static struct ctl_table ip_ct_sysctl_table[] = {
    {
        .procname   = "ip_conntrack_max",
        .maxlen     = sizeof(int),
        .mode       = 0644,
        .proc_handler   = proc_dointvec,
    },
    // ...
    {
        .procname   = "ip_conntrack_log_invalid",
        .maxlen     = sizeof(unsigned int),
        .mode       = 0644,
        .proc_handler   = proc_dointvec_minmax,
        .extra1     = &log_invalid_proto_min,
        .extra2     = &log_invalid_proto_max,
    },
    { }
};
```

Here an array of structs ends with `{ }`. For what purpose was it added?
By the way, a bit above this code there is another [array of structs](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_conntrack_l3proto_ipv4.c#L170), but without empty braces at the end.

When should I use empty braces at the end of an array of structs?

Comment: Hmm what if it added to signal the end of the array like 0 signal the end of the string? Just guessing.

Comment: This is some non-standard GCC extension. And as such, it very likely comes with little or no documentation... I just read all the docs and I can't find anything about empty struct initializer lists. Yet it compiles, unless you force strict ISO with `-pedantic`.

Comment: Anyway, it is a "sentinel" value, an item with everything set to zero/NULL to mark the end of the array.

Comment: Sentinels are also common in [CPython extension modules](https://docs.python.org/3.7/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This particular change was part of the [*sysctl net: Remove unused binary sysctl code*](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/f8572d8f2a2ba75408b97dc24ef47c83671795d7) commit by Eric W. Biederman, changing the initialization of the last element of the `ip_ct_sysctl_table` array from `{0}` to `{}` (and performs similar changes to many other array initializations).

The `{0}` pattern seems to have been around for much longer though, and both `{0}` or `{}` final element-initialization is commonly (in the Linux source code) explicitly referred to as `Terminating entry`, so it is likely a pattern present to allow consuming these arrays without knowing their lengths, terminating consumption when hitting the zero-initialized terminating entry. E.g. for the similar arrays in [`sound/aoa/fabrics/snd-aoa-fabric-layout.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/36f0bebd9865dc7e327777fca34b75e65cbfd1a6/sound/aoa/fabrics/snd-aoa-fabric-layout.c) the intent of the zero-initialization is even explicitly mentioned in a comment, e.g.:

> ```
> static struct codec_connection toonie_connections[] = {
>   {
>       .connected = CC_SPEAKERS | CC_HEADPHONE,
>       .codec_bit = 0,
>   },
>   {} /* terminate array by .connected == 0 */
> };
> ```

Comment: It would be interesting to know their rationale for dropping standard C in favour of a GCC extension that is 100% equivalent in terms of functionality. All it does is preventing the code from compiling on standard C compilers. That is, supposedly 100% equivalent because gcc doesn't seem to document this feature... This is _not_ a zero-length array, it's an empty initializer list.

Comment: @Lundin Would not `int arr[] = {}` (given that we are using the GNU empty initializer extension) result in an empty array; i.e., the size of `arr` being `0`?

Comment: @dfri: It can't in this case because the type of object being initialized is given rather than inferred.

Comment: @Lundin: I've seen some compilers (MSVC compiling in C mode several years ago, never looked on gcc) that will insist on individual initialization of the single explicitly initialized field followed by a `memset` to zero of the remaining fields, even though it could have zero-initialized the whole structure with a single `memset`. Not saying that's the rationale here, but it's possible it's trying to tell the compiler "zero-init everything in bulk" rather than "set first attribute to `0`, then zero-init the rest in bulk".

Comment: @Lundin On the flip side, I don't see why the C standards committee doesn't legalize `{}` for member-wise initialization to 0. `{0}` has the disadvantage of being less general since it requires that the first member not be an aggregate.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The behavior you describe would not be conformant (and strictly speaking, `memset` and member-wise initialization to 0 are not the same).

Comment: @dfri No, an initializer list cannot be empty in C.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Such compilers would be quite broken. MSVC has a very poor reputation in C mode, so looking at it for reference of how C compilers should behave will do you no good.

Comment: @jamesdlin: `{0}` works even for a subaggregate (or union); see 6.7.8p20.

Comment: This [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) page describes initialization rules well and in detail. This particular chapter of the standard isn't easy reading.

Comment: @Lundin: The cppreference page is however in conflict with the wording of ISO/IEC 9899:2011, which allows for that (§6.7.9 (21)). No initializers are undoubtly "fewer" than members of the aggregate. So that's not a queer compiler extension, but legitimate C.

Comment: @Damon It is not valid C and it's well-known... compile with gcc -pedantic-errors. To understand why, you need to read the actual syntax for an initializer list, top of 6.7.9. There must be at least one initializer. Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589533/is-an-empty-initializer-list-valid-c-code. Specifically `{ initializer-list }` then initializer list: `designation(opt) initializer` or `initializer-list , designation(opt) initializer`

Comment: @Lundin In this specific instance, no idea. But gcc extensions are used extensively in the linux kernel.

Answer (score 21):

You're probably familiar with zero-terminated strings. `ctl_table ip_ct_sysctl_table[]` is a zero-terminated array, i.e. the last array entry has all-zero members.

Comment: So going through the array, you know you have reached the end when e.g. `procname` is null, or `maxlen` is zero.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Well, the example is incomplete. `procname` could be a `char[100]` in which case it's `""`, not null. But otherwise yes.

Answer (score 13):

> What is the need of empty braces '{ }' at the end of array of structs?

To be clear: the "empty braces '{ }' at the end of array of structs" is not *needed* to satisfy C syntax requirements.

> When should I use empty braces at the end of an array of structs?

When code wants a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

It is sometimes *useful* for the program to have a final array element of all zeros - certainly to detect the end.  The *need* comes from the application's use of array `ctl_table ip_ct_sysctl_table[]`, not from a C language need.

Answer (score 9):

It's one zero initialized element at the end of the array in order to increase the number of elements of the array by one.

Consider this small demo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Test
{
  int x;
  int y;
} arr[] =
{
    {1,2},
    {3,4},
//  {}
};

int main(void) {
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

The size of the `arr` array will change if you uncomment the `{}` at the end of the array initialisation list.

**Outputs:**

With     `// {}` (array has 2 elements)

```
2
```

With     `{}` (array has 3 elements)

```
3
```

**Further explanation:**

The `ip_ct_sysctl_table` array is only used at one place, that is here:

```
in->ctl_table = kmemdup(ip_ct_sysctl_table,
                sizeof(ip_ct_sysctl_table),
                GFP_KERNEL);
```

The extra `{}` increases the total size `ip_ct_sysctl_table`.

Comment: That is not "in order to increase the number of elements of the array" but to signal the end of the array.

Comment: LOL, no.  The idea is that no-one so far has been able to explain it completely, with absolute certainty.  The closest statement of certainty is simply that the `{ }` is an initializer.  But _the why_ is still unclear.  Thus, for now anyway, the word _probably_ is probably a good idea. :)