# Initialize structure in C as empty or with zeros?

Tags: c

```
struct states
{
    float v, x;
};

struct 
{
    struct coeffs c1;
    struct states s1;
} cands;


main()
{
   // A: 
   cands.s1 = (struct states){   };
   // B:
   cands.s1 = (struct states){ 0 };
}
```

Microsoft compiler complains about A (`syntax error`), but works fine with B. GCC didn't complain about A.

Which one is right, A or B?
Are A and B the same?

Comment: *"Microsoft compiler complains about A,"* - complains **how** ? That specific warning/error belongs *in your question*.

Comment: Does  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589533/is-an-empty-initializer-list-valid-c-code answer your quesiton? I think there is somewhere in gcc documentation that it treats empty `{}` as `{0}`.

Comment: @WhozCraig MSVC gives `syntax error`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2059.

Comment: I understand. I'm saying when asking about the nature and/or validity of prospective error messages received from posted code, those error messages belong, *verbatim*, in your question; not omitted or in the general comment chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this structure and union initializer reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization):

> When initializing an object of struct or union type, the initializer must be a **non-empty**, brace-enclosed, comma-separated list of initializers for the members

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

The correct alternative is B.

Many compilers usually add many non-standard *extensions* to the base language by default. Such extensions are non-portable and I recommend against using them.

GCC apparently have such an extension for the empty brace list. If you add e.g. the option `-std=c11` when building then GCC will be stricter and not use non-standard extensions.