# Significance of last item in this array of structs

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization

How is the last item in `myarray` valid? Supposedly this is an "empty-terminated list". This is C code.

```
typedef struct sFoo
{
    char *a;
    char *b;
} SFOO;

static SFOO my_sfoo_array[] =
    {
        { 0x1000, 0x2000 },
        { 0x3000, 0x4000 },
        { }        /* what?! */
    };
```

Are the missing structure elements automatically supplied as `0`, so that the last entry `{ }` is really `{0, 0}`?

Comment: Simply put, yes.

Comment: I think it is not a standard thing though, but a compiler extension. Standard C does not allow empty initializers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a valid C initialization

```
static SFOO my_sfoo_array[] =
    {
        { 0x1000, 0x2000 },
        { 0x3000, 0x4000 },
        { }        /* what?! */
    };
```

C does not allow empty braces.

In C++ it means value initialization.

So in C it would be correctly to write

```
static SFOO my_sfoo_array[3] =
    {
        { 0x1000, 0x2000 },
        { 0x3000, 0x4000 },
    };
```

In this case the members of the third element will be initialized by null-pointers.
The initializer in C is defined like

```
initializer:
    assignment-expression
    { initializer-list }
    { initializer-list , }
```

as you can see the *initializer-list* is not optional.

Comment: Not valid in standard C, but is works in common compilers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589533/is-an-empty-initializer-list-valid-c-code/

Comment: @EugeneSh.  It does not matter what compiler allows such an initialization. We are speaking about C.

Comment: Remove a comma in the second snippet

Comment: @klutt It is allowed.;)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Really? Didn't know that.

Comment: @klutt Not only allowed, but considered a good practice (well, I guess depends). For example when you add another line to the arrays, it will be only that line shown in `diff`. While without the comma two lines will be different.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I find it a very good practice. Just didn't know it was allowed. Those kind of nice syntactic sugar is not very typical to C. :)