# Why is the first element of the int array different from the one appended in for loop?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, frequency, sentence

I have 2 questions.
First question is that, I'm trying to find the frequency of the sentence and put them into another array. However, the output of the new frequency `nfreq` is different from what is appended in for loop.

```
void append(char* s, char c) 
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    s[len] = c;
    s[len+1] = '\0';
}

int main()
{

    char str[] = "test sentence";
    char nstr[] = "";
    int freq[256] = {};
    int nfreq[256] = {};

    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        freq[str[i]]++;
    }
     
    printf("\nCharacter   Frequency\n");

    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(freq) / sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        if(freq[i] != 0)
        {
            printf("%5c%10d\n", i, freq[i]);  
            char c = i;
            append(nstr, c);
            int f = freq[i];
            nfreq[j] = f;
            printf("Num in nfreq[%d] is %d\n", j, nfreq[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(nstr); i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", nfreq[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("size of nfreq : %lu\n", sizeof(nfreq) / sizeof(nfreq[0]));
    printf("size of str : %lu\n", strlen(str));
    printf("size of nstr : %lu\n", strlen(nstr));
    printf("nstr is : %s\n", nstr);

    return 0;
}
```

The frequency of each letter is

```
Character   Frequency
              1
    c         1
    e         4
    n         2
    s         2
    t         3
```

and `nfreq` should have those `{1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3}` in its array with the code above and it even
says `Num in nfreq[0] is 1` and etc in the loop, but when I try to check what's in `nfreq` outside the loop, it outputs `{116, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3}` this instead. What is this `116` and it should be `1` for the frequency of `' '`.

Also the second question is that, if I were not to declare the size of an int array, `int nfreq[] = {}` like so in the beginning, does the size of this array, after appending int with for loop, changes dynamically? Or does it stay 0?

I tried fixing it by not declaring the size (which I don't think it matters) of `nfreq` array.
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Edit :
Sorry I forgot to add append function.

Comment: You are playing with fire... `char` may be a signed type so it shouldn't be used as array index.

Comment: Don't use `strlen` in a loop test when the string is loop-invariant.  It immediately turns an O(n) loop into an O(n^2) loop.  You wouldn't recalculate the string length every time if you were doing it by hand, right?  So why do you write code that does?

Comment: @TomKarzes Would the compiler be able optimize it out with -O0?

Comment: @Haris Well, -O0` disables optimization, so the call would not be moved out of the loop.  But even with optimization enabled, it would need to know that `strlen` is the library version of the function, and that the string doesn't change in the loop.  In any case, it's a bad habit to put `strlen` calls in a loop test.  It's a common beginner's mistake (and also something you see from people who are used to languages like Python, where string lengths are kept with the string).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> char nstr[] = "";
> ```

`nstr` is an array of **one** character.

> ```
> append(nstr, c);
> ...
> s[len+1] = '\0';
> ```

`len` is 0, so `len + 1` is 1. This line is writing out-of-bounds to `nstr`. `nstr` is `char [1]`. You can only `nstr[0] = something`. `nstr[1]` is invalid.

Do:

```
char nstr[256] = "";
```

> if I were not to declare the size of an int array, int nfreq[] = {} like so in the beginning, does the size of this array, after appending int with for loop, changes dynamically?

Notes: the `{}` is technically invalid, use `{0}` [Is an empty initializer list valid C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589533/is-an-empty-initializer-list-valid-c-code) . `int nfreq[] = {}` is technically invalid code, it doesn't make sense, if it would, then `nfreq` would have zero size.

There are *no* "dynamic" changes of array size. Array has constant size. Writing out-of-bounds to an array is an error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

### Invalid initialization:

```
int freq[256] = {};
```

is invalid. ISO C forbids empty initializer braces. An initializer-list must contain at least one initializer.

Perhaps:

```
int freq[256] = { 0 };
```

---

Re:

> if I were not to declare the size of an int array, int nfreq[] = {}
> like so in the beginning, does the size of this array, after appending
> int with for loop, changes dynamically? Or does it stay 0?

Answer: No.

```
int nfreq[] = {};
```

is not a valid statement. The space doesn't change dynamically.

Either declare an automatic array with fixed size like this:

```
int nfreq[SIZE] = { 0 };
```

or dynamically allocate memory with `malloc()`, and reallocate with `realloc()` as necessary.

---

### Incorrect format specifier:

`strlen()` and `sizeof()` returns a type `size_t`. `%lu` might not be the correct format specifier for `size_t`. Use `%zu` instead.
See also:

---

### Writing to out of bounds memory:

```
void append(char* s, char c) 
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    s[len] = c;
    s[len+1] = '\0';
}
```

You didn't allocate any memory for the array that has decayed to a pointer in `append()`. So this writes to out of bounds memory, and exhibits undefined behaviour.