# How to use designated initializers in structs inherited from another struct in C++20?

Tags: c++, struct, c++20, designated-initializer, inherited

```
int main()
{
    struct TStruct1 {
        int Field1;
        int Field2;
    };

    struct TStruct2 : TStruct1 {
        int Tag;
    };

    TStruct2 t2{
        {
            .Field1 = 1,
            .Field2 = 2,
        },
        .Tag = 3
    };
}
```

leads to `cannot mix designated-initializers with non-designated-initializers` error in MSVC (error message can be another in clang).

Is it possible to use designated initializers in `struct` which inherited from another `struct`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876657/260313