# Using Designated Initializer on member of inherited base class

Tags: c++, parameters, named

I created a class `Something` which holds a member variable.

I am able to do this, which works as intended:

```cpp
struct Something
{
    bool Works;
};

int main()
{
    Something s = {
        .Works = false,
    };
}
```

Now, I want to created a struct inherited from `Something`, named `Something2`, and want to do the same thing, but I want to be able to have access to `Something::Works` (which I renamed `DoesntWork`, since it doesn't work!):

```cpp
struct Something
{
    bool DoesntWork;
};

struct Something2 : public Something
{
    bool Works;
};


int main()
{
    Something2 s2 = {
        .Works = true,
        .DoesntWork = false,
    };
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rYT3br467

I am not looking for an alternative, I can already think of some. I am only wondering if this is possible, and if yes then how.

If it is not possible, I would really like to know the low-level reason, so don't hesitate!

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Nathan Oliver's comment, you can read: [Designated initializers in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876020/designated-initializers-in-c20)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers

Comment: Thank you, I did not know how that was called and that answers the question

Comment: No problem.  Not knowing the terminology makes it really hard to search for.

Comment: @NathanOliver _"Not knowing the terminology makes it really hard to search for"_ <- Me, searching for solutions to problems (I've decided are) in the math domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is **much** stricter when it comes to designated initializers than C.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

> out-of-order designated initialization, **nested designated initialization**, **mixing of designated initializers and regular initializers**, and designated initialization of arrays are all supported in the C programming language, but **are not allowed in C++**.

C doesn't have the inheritance concept at all which makes C's version of designating (at least untill C++20) impossible. One possible, future, version would be to designate it "forward" as often done in constructors with delegating constructors. In that case, I'd expect the proper initialization to be this:

```cpp
Something2 s2 = {
    Something = {
        .Works = false
    },
    .DoesntWorks = true
};
```

That's however not part of C++ as of C++20. You can however create constructors in C++ to accommodate (part of) your needs without designated initializers:

```cpp
struct Something {
    bool DoesntWork;
};

struct Something2 : public Something {
    Something2(bool Doesnt, bool Does) : 
        Something{Doesnt}, 
        Works{Does} 
    {}
    bool Works;
};

int main() {
    Something2 s2
    {
        true, false
    }; 
}
```

or initialize each object without user defined constructors at all:

```cpp
struct Something {
    bool DoesntWork;
};

struct Something2 : public Something {
    bool Works;
};

int main() {
    Something2 s2{
        // You could just make it `{true}` below, but mentioning the
        // subobject fits the purpose of a designated initializer for clarity:
        Something{true},
        // this must however be left unmentioned in C++20 since you can't
        // mix regular initializers with designated ones:
        false
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
struct Something
{
    bool ThisWorks;
};

struct Something2 : Something
{
    bool Works;
};


int main()
{
    Something2 s2 = {
        { .ThisWorks = false },
        .Works = true
    };
}
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tvr6h176K)

Comment: Only with complier extensions not turned off though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo dang, OK. Didn't realize this was an extension. It was just the first logical thing I tried and it worked.

Comment: Yepp - me too :-)